# convert regular expression from c# to javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, expression

Can someone help me convert this c# regular express (email validation) to Javascript?

```
@"^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$
```

Comment: That looks like a simple regex for email addresses. I'm kinda sure that's actually not what it does (well).

Comment: It looks like it should work as is.

Comment: or you could just look for one one the web http://www.bing.com/search?q=javascript+regex+email

Comment: http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Answer (score 0):

It should work pretty much as is<sup>1</sup>:

```
var address = . . .;
var r = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;

if (address.match(r)) {
    // address is okay
}
```

<sup>1</sup> That is, it should work in JavaScript as well as it does in C#. Email validation is actually quite complex and your C# regex is really not very good for this. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address).